# Quartz.NET fires a job multiple times

Tags: reset, jobs, quartz.net, multiple-instances

I am fairly new to Quertz.NET. I am inheriting a Windows Service that uses Quartz.NET to schedule jobs.

There is a job that schedules all other jobs (say ResetJobs: IJobs). It downloads the job list from a database nightly at 9pm, deletes all the scheduled jobs, schedules/starts the jobs in the downloaded job list. One of the jobs in the downloaded list is the ResetJobs itself.

When the windows services starts, the service downloads the job list (including the ResetJobs) and schedules them.  When the ResetJob fires at the cronjob time (0 0 21 1/1 * ? *), it immediately runs 10 times. The service log shows 10 calls to the ResetJob. The service itself runs on a single physical machine, not on a clustered environment. [DisallowConcurrentExecution] attribute is on the ResetJob class but doesn't help. The ResetJob still runs 10 times when fired.

I don't know if this is the root cause but when the ResetJob fires, it deletes itself from the scheduler and schedule it again. If this is the bad design, I would like to know how to do this properly.

Thanks

Comment: I should mention that ONLY the ResetJob fires multiple times. None of other jobs does that.

Comment: DisallowConcurrentExecution will ensure that multiple instances won't run at the same time, I suspect your jobs are launching 10 times, one after the other. My best guess is that you have some bad logic in your deleting/scheduling, can't know for sure without seeing the code. Try to avoid rescheduling the ResetJob itself on each execution.

Comment: It seems that you may have a bunch of resetjob jobs scheduled. You get 10 instances firing because you probably have 10 threads running. Then the jobs get cleared out and the process starts over again. Hard to tell without more details

Comment: @Alioza and jvilalta,  you are both correct.  The job runs 10 times based on a setting from another source.  Thanks.